# Parts of my floor plane disappear

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering

I'm having a problem rendering. The object in question is a large plane consisting of two triangles. It should cover most of the area of the window, but parts of it disappear and reappear with the camera moving and turning (I never see the whole plane though)

Note that the missing parts are NOT whole triangles.

I have messed around with the camera to find out where this is coming from, but I haven't found anything.
I haven't added view frustum culling yet.

I'm really stuck as I have no idea at which part of my code I even have to look at to solve this. Searches mainly turn up questions about whole triangles missing, this is not what's happening here.

Any pointers to what the cause of the problem may be?

Edit:
I downscaled the plane and added another texture that's better suited for testing.
Now I have found this behaviour:

[This looks like I expect it to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVJBE.png)

[If I move forward a bit more, this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLFCS.png)

It looks like the geometry behind the camera is flipped and rendered even though it should be invisible?

Edit 2:
my vertex and fragment shaders:

```
#version 330
in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;

out vec4 pass_textureCoords;

uniform mat4 MVP;


void main() {
  gl_Position = MVP * vec4(position, 1);
  pass_textureCoords = vec4(textureCoords/gl_Position.w, 0, 1/gl_Position.w);
  gl_Position = gl_Position/gl_Position.w;
}



  #version 330

in vec4 pass_textureCoords;

out vec4 fragColor;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

void main()
{
fragColor= texture(textureSampler, pass_textureCoords.xy/pass_textureCoords.w);
}
```

Comment: Check your z-near value.

Comment: I already did. And a problem with z-near wouldn't cause the right half of the plane to disappear as well, would it?

Comment: Are you doing any culling? If that's not it either, then you might be doing something codewise, which we can't tell without looking at it. It might also be a driver issue, have you tried it on another computer?

Comment: Backface culling, back I already tried turning that of and it doesn't change the issue.
I'd be happy to post code, but I have no idea where this even COULD come from...
So far I haven't tried it on another computer, will do that.

Comment: Meant more like frustum culling gone bad. However try on another computer, to see whether it could be a driver issue.

Comment: You should use GPU debug software, like Intel GPA, nVidia nSight, RenderDoc. By any of this apps, you can see how you mesh changing thru pipeline and it can give you invaluable insight.

Comment: I will look into that, but I still don't know what I'm even looking for.

Comment: As I said, you must check how plane mesh goes thru the pipeline. It could be vertex or index buffers, binding, incorrect matrices, wrong draw call parameters, incorrect vertex shader. W/o any code it's hard to tell anything specific.

Answer (score 0):

Many drivers do not handle big triangles that cross the z-plane very well, as depending on your precision settings and the drivers' internals these triangles may very well generate invalid coordinates outside of the supported numerical range.

To make sure this is not the issue, try to manually tessellate the floor in a few more divisions, instead of only having two triangles for the whole floor.

Doing so is quite straightforward. You'd have something like this pseudocode:

```
division_size_x = width / max_x_divisions
division_size_y = height / max_y_divisions

for i from 0 to max_x_divisions:
    for j from 0 to max_y_divisions:
        vertex0 = { i * division_size_x, j * division_size_y }
        vertex1 = { (i+1) * division_size_x, j * division_size_y }
        vertex2 = { (i+1) * division_size_x, (j+1) * division_size_y }
        vertex3 = { i * division_size_x, (j+1) * division_size_y }
        OutputTriangle(vertex0, vertex1, vertex2)
        OutputTriangle(vertex2, vertex3, vertex0)
```

Comment: I replaced the plane with one with higher tesselation. It does impove the behavior, but it doesn't entirely fix it. Now I'm not sure if it isn't whole triangles disappearing though.

Comment: That is not true. Any normal rasterizer will divide triangle by near z-plane, otherwise, projection matrix won't work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is an error in my matrices that caused problems with vertices that are behind the camera. I deleted all the divisions by w in my shaders and did glPosition = -gl_Position (initially just to test something), it works now.
I still need to figure out the exact problem but it is working for now.

Comment: "perspective division" by "w" is something that OpenGL does on its own. You only need to do it yourself in rare cases, when you play with projection between shaders.